# tftpy package sytax errors on import

Tags: python, exception, syntax-error, tftp

I've just installed the package tftpy version 0.6.2 when I import it I get a syntax error with the line:
running the code:

```
import tftpy
```

I get the error:
raise ImportError, "Requires at least Python 2.3"

SyntaxError: Invalid syntax

I have version 3.6.3 installed.

```
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```

gives me the out put major=3, minor=6, micro=3.

However the line of code that raises the syntax error is the last line in the code below:

```
import sys
required_version = (2, 3)
if sys.version_info < required_version:
    raise ImportError, "Requires at least Python 2.3"
```

I don't think the issue is with my version number I think it doesn't like the syntax used to raise the ImportError exception.
Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: Maybe this can help you, i was seeing the issues and PR of `tftpy` on github, and appears that something it's been done.
[Follow the link.](https://github.com/internap/fake-switches/pull/79)

Comment: Thanks it seems like the fix is to change the lines of code which throw the exceptions from: raise ExceprionName, "Exception Message" to raise ExceptionName("Exception Message")

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in my case.
When you run a tftpy server, you need to run it as sudo, therefor you need to install tftpy as sudo also.

In my case:

```
$ sudo pip3 install tftpy
$ sudo python3 tftpy-program.py
```

Also remember that if you use python3, f.eks, you need to install the package with pip3, and not jsut pip. Hope it helps.